# Compare one item of a dictionary to another item in a dictionary one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Currently I'm working on an assignment where I have to compare an answer key(dictionary) to answers from students(dictionary). I have to count how many of the students answers match the answer key and return that value. I realize my current code is comparing one whole dictionary to the other and if they're all equal then it will return a value but if not it returns 0. I'm just not sure how to fix it so it returns the number of ones that match.

This is my current code. Here is the previous function forgot to add it.

```
def index_responses(responses):
results = {}
count = 1
for answer in responses:
    """
    makes a dictionary containing the responses of the student
    and mapping it to a key of Q" " depending on wht number question it is.
    """
    results["Q" + str(count)] = answer[0]
    count += 1
return results
```

[image: My current for this problem]

Comment: post code. dont post pictures.dont post links. reasons: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode  indent code lines by 4 spaces to mark it as code. or select it and hit the **{}** button

Comment: what is index_responses() ? your code only shows undefined functions or lists - no dicts in sight - only usage of dict-method

Comment: You need to individually extract the keys and values from each dictionary. Right now, you're comparing entire lists within a loop

Comment: if you iterate a dicts items - why are you not using the item you are iterating. Why are you comparing answers.items() to response.items() inside a loop over the answers.items() itself...

Comment: Your function `index_responses` assigns the 0th answer to all Questions ... also it lacks proper indentatiojn. Please fix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the keys (here, `prompt`) of both dictionaries are the same, or at least for every key in the answers dictionary, there is a matching response prompt, then you can count them like so

```
count = 0
for prompt, response in responses.items():
    if response == answers.get(prompt, None):
        count += 1
return count
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I need! thank you!